# What are the key phonetic differences between British English and Australian English?

Tags: phonetics, phonology

Due to historic reasons, they are somewhat similar (for example, both British and Australian speakers usually pronounce 'a' in words like 'hat' as [a] instead of [æ] as Americans would do). However, they sound distinctly different, but it's hard for me to point out those differences exactly. Would you do that?

Comment: Is this just for BrE received pronunciation? Otherwise there are many dialects of BrE alone that would make comparison difficult. (I can think of at least 3 different BrE pronunciations of hat *off the top of my head*)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects

Comment: @Smock RP 5 more to go...

Comment: @userr2684291 Thanks, but it's quite confusing (not because of the symbols but because of the way it's structured)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_English_phonology